# В LiveData есть ли аналог flatMap RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, livedata

Есть ли в LiveData из Jetpack аналог flatMap RxJava ? Мне нужно сделать сетевой запрос, дождаться его результата, и используя его результат тут же сделать следующий другой сетевой запрос. Спасибо всем за любую помощь

Comment: а зачем для такой задачи flatMap или его эквивалент?

Comment: Я с помощью flatMap могу сделать цепочку сетевых запросов которые буду ждать результат от другого и делать свой запрос. Как с помощью LiveData сделать тоже самое что и flatMap?

Comment: Нет никакого эквивалента `flatMap` в `LiveData`, потому что `LiveData` - это не про реактивные потоки данных. Это observable (паттерн Наблюдатель), который держит в себе какие-то данные,  только ещё учитывает жизненный цикл activity или fragment и не посылает оповещение подписчикам о новых данных, если они не находятся в нужном (`isAtLeast(STARTED)`)  состоянии. При этом, если данные несколько раз обновились, пока подписчики были неактивными, то когда они станут активными, они получат только последние данные

Comment: Хм, ну LiveData же можно использовать вместе с Retrofit например, как тогда мне сделать несколько взаимозависящих сетевых запросов? Использовать RxJava ? Мне важно учитывать жизненный цикл активити или фрагмента. Чтобы когда я сделаю поворот экрана во время сетевых запросов, все не пошло крахом. По сути проблема в том, что я на данный момент не понимаю как в RxJava обрабатывать жизненный цикл активити. Поэтому ищу пути с LiveData.

Comment: А тут не нужно делать выбор между LiveData и RxJava, их используют вместе. В ViewModel содержится LiveData и на неё подписываются из активити/фрагмента (забыл ещё упомянуть, то если активити/фрагмент уничтожаются, то LiveData отписывает их подписчиков автоматически). Через RxJava в ViewModel делаются сетевые или БД запросы (для Retrofit есть специальный [адаптер](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2), который позволяет возвращать Single/Observable и другие), результаты которых записываются в liveData (в subscribe)

Answer (score 1):

Есть Transformations.switchMap()

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations